# Get audio file at random from already mapped arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, dictionary, jbutton

Sorry, I have a hitch to fix, I was able to map a File array with a String array, and now, I want to get a random File from the mapped arraylist to play when a button is clicked, but I don't get it.... It doesn't work...

**Here's my code:**

```
private static File[] word =
//Here, I announce the contents of the File array named word, about 50 Files

private String []answer =  
//String array to be mapped with File array         
//Other swing parameters to be used

private static JLabel sound;
private static JButton check;
private static JTextField spell;
private JButton click;

//Font to be used for all text typed in JTextField
private Font fonty;
//Icon to be displayed when sound is played
JLabel icon = new JLabel (new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Pictures\\Photos\\#010.jpg"));

public Quest1() {
    // Mapping of String array to File array
    Map<String, File> mapping = new HashMap();
    Map<String, File>mpl = new HashMap();

    mpl.putAll(mapping);
    //Layout for the JFrame set (the class extends JFrame)

    setLayout (new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(icon);

    fonty = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    //JPanel to hold swing components
    JPanel hold = new JPanel ();
    hold.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();

    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    g.gridx = 2;
    g.gridy = 1;
    g.gridwidth = 2;
    g.insets = new Insets(2, 20, 2,2);

    sound = new JLabel (new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\JLabelSoundImage.jpg"));
    sound.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,70));
    hold.add(sound, g);

    click = new JButton ("Play");
    click.setFont(fonty);
    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    g.gridx = 2;
    g.gridy = 5;
    g.gridwidth = 2;
    g.insets = new Insets(2, 20, 8, 2);
    hold.add(click, g);

    click.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent t) {
            //Where my Problem lies.... getting a random File from the mapped array list to play when the button is clicked.
            List key = new ArrayList (mapping.keySet());
            Collections.shuffle(key);
            for (Object o: key){
                mapping.get(o);

                InputStream in = new InputStream(mapping.get(o),(word));
            }   
        }
    });

    spell = new JTextField (10);
    spell.setFont(fonty);
    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    g.gridx = 5;
    g.gridy = 2;
    g.gridwidth = 3;
    g.insets = new Insets (2, 2, 2, 20);
    hold.add (spell, g);

    check = new JButton ("Check my answer");
    check.setFont(fonty);
    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    g.gridx = 8;
    g.gridy = 8;
    g.gridwidth = 3;
    g.insets = new Insets (2, 2, 20, 2);
    hold.add (check, g);

    check.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            if (spell.getText().equals(mapping.get(key))) {
                String c = "Correct!";

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
            }
            else {
                String d = ("Wrong! the Answer is ") + (mapping.get(key)) ;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, d);
            }
        }
    });

    hold.setVisible(true);
    hold.setSize(400,400);
    hold.setLocation(50, 50);
    hold.setOpaque(false);

    add(hold, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Read how to create a [mcve] and then edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is not providing the type to your List. This is very risky, so define what type of List it actually is:

```
List<File> ...
```

Another problem is mpl.keySet returns a Set, not an ArrayList. You also don't really want to redefine this every time they click the button. Set this Set once, after you've defined your Map.

```
Set<File> songs = mpl.keySet();
File[] songArray = songs.toArray();
```

At this point, all you need to do is generate an index and then create a local variable with a reference to the file. This can be done with the Math class.

```
int index = (int) (Math.random() * songArray.length);
File song = songArray[index];
```

You may need to add 1 to the index at the end. I don't recall if it will be inclusive or exclusive for all indices.

Comment: Hey, Can you put it all in one syntax, I'm finding it difficult to apply it through.... thanks for the response!